# How to set "Next Input Source" shortcut in macOS Sierra to Shift + Cmd?

Tags: shortcut, input-source

It seems not possible to set "Next Input Source" shortcut in macOS Sierra to <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> with the default OS facilities at the moment.

*It there a way to do it with any third-party applications?*

Comment: That would preclude you from ever using shift/cmd/anything_else, which is presumably why the system won't let you do it.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you for the remark! Still, I would like to use that shortcut for now, even if i brings such restrictions.